# Black Screen With just a cursor on Boot

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Precision 7730, intel i9 hexacore, 64GB Ram, 500GB HD, Radeon

20.04.03 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-99-generic x86_64)

```
 *NOT* dual boot
 *NOT* NVidia
 Did *not* just upgrade to a new major version.
```

My machine was running fine yesterday.  I decided to turn it off at end of day.  The next morning, I noticed it had not turned completely off, but had a black screen (but you could tell power was still on).   NP, I touched the power button and it shut off.  After restarting, it comes up to a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I *can* boot off of a CD with an Ubuntu 20.04.03, and everything works fine there.  Also did a hardware diagnostic with no problems reported.

I've now spent hours attempting everything I could find here and elsewhere.  Here is a summary of what I've done, all followed by a reboot, so far nothing has worked:

---

```
 apt --fix-missing install | apt-get update | apt -full-upgrade
 apt-get install --fix-broken
 removed all cache (though my HD wasn't near full)
 restarted gdm3
 removed, reinstalled and reconfigured gdm3
 removed, reinstalled and reconfigured xserver-xorg
 Tried previous kernel from grub menu
 Tried from recovery mode on existing and previous kernel
```

At this point, when I ran 'sudo egrep "xorg|WW|EE" /var/log/syslog'
It reported an error with /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamorgl.so

backed up and then restored all xorg modules from a 15 day old backup

Now, when I run 'sudo egrep "xorg|WW|EE" /var/log/syslog'

I'm getting a large number of errors:

---

```
 amdgpu module ABI major version (23) does not match the server's version (24)
```

So, restored xorg modules back to what they were.

Now I'm back to the glamor initialization failed after loading the libglamoregl.so.

---

Tried the following to no avail:

```
 modified /etc/default/grub changing the line to:
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
 sudo update-grub
```

** Another note:  I *can* use lightdm, but it doesn't accept my credentials.  So I'm thinking it has something to do with gdm3.

** Another Note:  I confirmed the error with libglamoregl.so started last night at 9:09PM (my time), which is the time I selected to shut down the system.

** Followed the steps here to no avail:

```
 https://linuxhint.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-without-reinstalling/
```

** Tried the following to no avail:

```
 sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

 ** added 'blacklist radeon'

 sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
 sudo shutdown -r now
```

Tried a different search around the internet, and I may have been on a tangent all day.   Not sure how to copy the output, as I'm posting this from another computer, but there are other errors surrounding 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' exiting with status 1.  This is followed by errors about not being able to open the display.  specifically:

```
-- The job identifier is 3425. 
Feb 16 08:34:14 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 NetworkManager[1583]: <info>  [1645022054.1422] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL 
Feb 16 08:34:14 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 NetworkManager[1583]: <info>  [1645022054.1450] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS 
Feb 16 08:34:14 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 whoopsie[2439]: [08:34:14] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com 
Feb 16 08:34:14 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 whoopsie[2439]: [08:34:14] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1 
Feb 16 08:34:14 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 whoopsie[2439]: [08:34:14] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1 
Feb 16 08:34:14 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 whoopsie[2439]: [08:34:14] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1 
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 whoopsie[2439]: [08:34:15] online 
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 dbus-daemon[3618]: [session uid=1001 pid=3618] Activating service name='org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' requested by ':1.15' (uid=1001 pid=3705 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground" label="unconfined") 
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 unknown[4580]: cannot open display:  
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 dbus-daemon[3618]: [session uid=1001 pid=3618] Activated service 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' failed: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1 
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 gnome-keyring-d[3705]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1 
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 gnome-keyring-daemon[3705]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1 
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 goa-daemon[3667]: secret_password_lookup_sync() returned NULL 
Feb 16 08:34:15 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter[4580]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused 
Feb 16 08:34:16 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 dbus-daemon[3618]: [session uid=1001 pid=3618] Activating service name='org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' requested by ':1.15' (uid=1001 pid=3705 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground" label="unconfined") 
Feb 16 08:34:16 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter[4583]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused 
Feb 16 08:34:16 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 gcr-prompter[4583]: cannot open display:  
Feb 16 08:34:16 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 dbus-daemon[3618]: [session uid=1001 pid=3618] Activated service 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' failed: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1 
Feb 16 08:34:16 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 gnome-keyring-daemon[3705]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1 
Feb 16 08:34:16 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 gnome-keyring-d[3705]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1 
Feb 16 08:34:16 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 goa-daemon[3667]: secret_password_lookup_sync() returned NULL Feb 16 08:34:24 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state. 
Feb 16 08:35:01 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 CRON[4597]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) 
Feb 16 08:35:01 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 CRON[4598]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1) 
Feb 16 08:35:01 josephmmorgan-Precision-7730 CRON[4597]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Now... no more help to be found.  I have no ideas.

Please help.

Comment: ONE not simply just uninstall some crucial package without read its logs (insert meme here). and blacklist radeon module without any reason (insert another meme here).

Comment: First of all, try to boot up from recovery mode and perform `$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` to reinstall. if you can, please put the output in your post. Good luck.

Comment: Matthias - my actions aren't random nor uninformed.  I've ignored many hundreds of suggestions because they don't fit my case.  However, some of the actions are just relatively harmless attempts (can't break it more) kinds of things that might just fix it.  I have looked at logs, and the issue continues to surround libglamoregl.so, which I have replaced from backups and working computers, all to no avail.

Comment: Also, I should have added the --fix-broken in the original.  Right now, it does nothing.  Final line of output is:    0 upgraded, o newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Could you please update yor post clarifying the error stage status? (libglamoregl.so or nomodeset value in grub).

Comment: What do you mean by "error stage status"?   When I set 'nomodeset', nothing at all was different.  Same errors show up WRT libglamoregl.so.

Comment: It's a bit confused about how to abroad/read the issue explained in your post. if you can make a well-ordered followed steps that you're followin' i'll agree you.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you can enter to recovery mode, try to repair/reinstall the radeon drivers, xorg-server and mesa...

Comment: Matthias.  Before I re-install the drivers, xorg-server and mesa, see the new notes in the post.  I'm thinking now it may have something to do with the keyring.  So far, I haven't found any way to actually correct that situation.

Comment: Reinstalling is much faster - would've been done already in less than half of the time you already wasted - than trying to fix this.

Comment: ChanganAuto:  You may be right.  I made a backup of my home directory, so I'm good there.  If I re-install, will I be a slave to rebuilding all my installed apps for the next several days?

Comment: Matthias - As recommended - did a full purge and reinstall or xorg-server, mesa and radio drivers.  No joy.     I believe at this point I have no other choice but to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Remember set a swap partition =) ! good luck